# catn't ping other netns

Tags: linux, networking, namespaces

On my centos7, I have set two netns ns1 and ns2, two veth pairs(tap2 and tap2_peer,tap3 and tap3_peer). tap2 was moved to ns1 and tap3 was moved to ns2. tap2's ip is 192.168.100.2/24.tap2_peer's ip is 192.168.100.1/24.tap3's ip is 192.168.200.2/24.tap3_peer's ip is 192.168.200.1/24. Following are route setting in different ns:

root netns

```
[root@VM-0-2-centos ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap2_peer
192.168.200.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap3_peer
```

ns1

```
[root@VM-0-2-centos ~]# ip netns exec ns1 route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 tap2
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap2
```

ns2

```
[root@VM-0-2-centos ~]# ip netns exec ns2 route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 tap3
192.168.200.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap3
```

So why in ns1 ping 192.168.200.1 is ok, but when ping 192.168.200.2, nothing happens. how can i fix it?

```
[root@VM-0-2-centos ~]# ip netns exec ns1 ping 192.168.200.1
PING 192.168.200.1 (192.168.200.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.200.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.020 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.200.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.200.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
^C
--- 192.168.200.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.020/0.028/0.033/0.007 ms
```

```
[root@VM-0-2-centos ~]# ip netns exec ns1 ping 192.168.200.2
PING 192.168.200.2 (192.168.200.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

how to fix the problem and why?

Comment: A well written problem description, but please learn to read the text of the tags you include on your questions. StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve `if/then/else` programming code problems (and tools). Please delete youquestion here and repost to [unix.se] . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't set up the proper routing between the two network namespaces. So you need to add the appropriate routes in each namespace. In ns1, you need to add a route to the ns2 network namespace and in ns2, you need to add a route to the ns1 network namespace. Also make sure that IP forwarding is enabled on your CentOS 7 system.

Comment: ip forwarding had been enabled. the problem wasn't fixed yet. The lo was down in both two ns when i inspected the network interfaces. I set up the two lo interfaces and it turn to be ok. But i don't why it works.